# Dynamically initialize dropzone.js in Ajax-loaded Form

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, dropzone.js

I would like to use dropzone.js in a dynamically loaded form. This is my actual code.

Implement the source and set autodiscover to false

```html
<script src="scripts/dropzone.min.js"></script>
<script>
  Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;
</script>
```

I load the Form with jquery

```js
$.ajax({
  method: "GET",
  url: "form.php",
  data: { user_id: userId }
}).done(function( result ) {
  $( ".user-details-"+userId ).append( result );
  var myDropzone = new Dropzone("div.dropzone", {
    url: "imageupload.ajax.php",
  });
});
```

After the html-result from the ajax-call is appended to my div.user-details the dropzone works without problems. But when I close the Form (remove from dom) and load it again I´ve got the error "Dropzone already attached." in my console.

This error also occours, if I change the initialization and use a div with a unique id.

How can I destroy the dropzone after remove the form from the dom?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you are using a class selector `div.dropzone`

So you should check if this class exists...& if exists does it already contains a dropzone..make it empty  $('div.dropzone').empty();

another way would to be to use dynamic ID

```
  var myDropzone = new Dropzone("div#dropzone", {
```

Comment: The div.dropzone doesn´t contains a dropzone because it was loaded with ajax into the dom. Dynamic ID myDropzone = new Dropzone("div#profileimage_"+internalUserID, {}); also doesn´t work.

Answer (score 1):

```
var element = document.getElementById("#Your-DropZone-Element")
if (element.dropzone) {
    element.dropzone.destroy();
}
```

Comment: Usually, it's better to explain your solution, instead of just posting a bunch of code lines.